# vscode python jedi client: couldn't create connection to server

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jedi

I keep getting this message when I run Jupyter Notebook.

- comment :

[image: 1]

- output:

[image: 2]

Comment: I think you should probably ask here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/

Answer (score 9):

Pylance is now the default language server ([see here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/05/11/vscode-python-may21.aspx#:%7E:text=Pylance%20is%20now%20the%20default,Python%20Extension%20for%20VS%20Code)). As such, I resolved the issue by changing my settings.json to:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```

You may need to install the Pylance extension, if you don't already have it.

Answer (score 4):

I met this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with python interpreter python3.6.9 + VS code python extension 2022.14

- If I downgrade the VS code python extension to 2022.06, it works.
- If I install a new version python (e.g. python3.9), it works.

So the reason should be:

**The new version python extension is not compatible with old python version 3.6.9.**

Solution:

**either downgrade the python extension to 2022.06(can be even earlier, not fully tested); or upgrade the python interpreter version.**

Comment: it is my case. After changing interpreter env 3.6 -> to -> 3.8 all error pop-ups disappeared.

Comment: yeah this works when using an older python version thank you

Answer (score 1):

i installed an extension named "Pylance" then restarted vs code, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the following code is specified correctly in your setting.json:

```
"python.languageServer":"Jedi"
```

Comment: I did as instructed, but the comment is still showing up.

Comment: @Insu Gim Could you please provide more information so that I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Change `python.languageServer` value to `Default` is work for me.